# Regular Expression to limit characters to 5000

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to simply limit the number of characters in a textarea  to 5000.
If there are more secure regular expressions I could use, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using? there may be a built in mechanism for this.

Comment: Just seems like a totally odd thing to do. Why use a Regex for this at all? Surely a simple limit on the string length of the textarea text would be easier to manage and avoid starting the regular expression engine every time someone adds something to the text?

Comment: I am using cForms for WordPress.  It has built-in support for RegEx, but I'm not sure how to go about adding a string limit length to it.

Answer (score 8):

`^.{0,5000}$` should work. Although using a regular expression for this is probably an odd choice.

Comment: Agree with this answer - especially the "odd choice". OP - do you have a valid reason to want to do this with Regex? What's wrong with string.length?

Comment: Note that dot normally doesn't match newline, so the string "a\nb" won't match, even though it's just three characters long.

Answer (score 4):

You will always get the job done with:

`^[\s\S]{0,5000}$`

- First there´s a character class that says: match whitespace (`\s`) or non-whitespace (`\S`) -- i.e any possible character
- Repeat that between zero and 5000 times.